# mod_reweite htaccess not work with a point in var

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I creating a mod_rewrite rule like this

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}\.php !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./page.php?key=$1
```

it works! But I want to do this:

```
www.site.com/var1.var2.var3
```

(variables are separated by point) separated by - or _ no problems, but if I put the point does not work why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are trying a rule like this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).(.*).(.*)$ ./page.php?key=$1&key2=$2&key3=$3
```

but you should remember to escape the dots which you want to interpret as periods.  There are many ways to right this but here is a simple way if you are new to `.htaccess` files:

```
RewriteEngine  On
RewriteBase    /

# Skip existing files or directories
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}     -d [OR] 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}     -f
RewriteRule ^                      -  [L]

# Add default PHP extension when appropriate
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^.*                    $0.php  [L]

# Pick up 1,2 and 3 parameter versions 
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.^(.*?)\.(.*)$ page.php?key=$1&key2=$2&key3=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.(.*?)$        page.php?key=$11&key2=$2        [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.$             page.php?key=$1                 [QSA,L]
```

Note:

- the first rule uses "^" as a pattern which always matches and the "-" means don't replace it.
- the second uses $0 which means the entire match pattern
- rule 3-5 match the 3,2,1 parameter options
- the [L] (last) flag means skip the rest of the rules
- you will need the QSA flag is you use other parameters.

The reason for splitting the existance check in to is that you need to handle files such as CSS and image (PNG/GIF/PNG) files as well as your application syntax.